# Get trending topics of twitter api with C#

Tags: api, google-trends, trending

I get "401 Unauthorized" error while trying to get the current trends using the twitter api but the below code work fine if I try to get some other response like user_timeline,available,tweets. Below is my code please tell me where iam wrong.

```
        var oauth_token = "****";
        var oauth_token_secret = "****";
        var oauth_consumer_key = "****";
        var oauth_consumer_secret = "****";

        // oauth implementation details
        var oauth_version = "1.0";
        var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

        // unique request details
        var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
            new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
        var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow
            - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        // message api details
        var status = "Updating status via REST API if this works";
        //var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
        //var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
       // var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json";
        var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/available.json";
        //var screen_name = "screenname";
        var query = "india";
        var id = "1";
        // create oauth signature
        //var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                       // "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&screen_name={6}";
        //var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
            //"&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&q={6}";
        var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                        "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&id={6}";

        var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                    oauth_consumer_key,
                                    oauth_nonce,
                                    oauth_signature_method,
                                    oauth_timestamp,
                                    oauth_token,
                                    oauth_version,
                                    id);

        baseString = string.Concat("GET&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

        var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                                "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

        string oauth_signature;
        using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
        {
            oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
                hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
        }

        // create the request header
        var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
                           "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " +
                           "oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " +
                           "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

        var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                        );


        // make the request

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        //var postBody = "screen_name=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(screen_name);
        //var postBody = "q=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(query);
        var postBody = "id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(id);
       // resource_url += "?" + postBody;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        string responseData = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You are not authorized to get the current trends. Check your privileges.

Comment: @LajosArpad but i getting response for other request like user_timeline, search tweets

Comment: They might require different types of privileges.